# How to get css for bootstrap-fileupload (using bootstrap-sass gem)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use the bootstrap-fileupload.js (http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) in my rails project but the bootstrap-sass css is missing the styling for bootstrap-fileupload elements.

I cannot even find a separate css on the twitter bootstrap customize site - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html. Fileupload is not listed as an option under the JS components.

Any pointers on how to do this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, just realized that this was extended by Jasny. Got the css at github.

Comment: Ok add your answer so that people can know you found answer & might help others too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, just realized that this was extended by Jasny. You can get the css at https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/blob/master/less/jasny/fileupload.less

updated link

Comment: Just download the project, open jasny-bootstrap.css and look for .fileupload - it's not that large of a file